# didReceiveRemoteNotification in AppDelegate not called for silent push notifications with notification service extension

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-extensions

I have a notification service extension for my app for modifying my regular push notifications, which works fine. The `didReceive` method in the extension is overriding the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in AppDelegate. However, if I send a silent notification or just a notification without the 'mutable-content' parameter set to true, the extension is not called (as expected). But, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called either, so I have no way to handle the notification.

Without the extension, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is being called on silent notifications and notifications without 'mutable-content' set.
Shouldn't it be called in my case as well? Or am I misunderstanding something about the extension?

Comment: Have you figured this out by any chance?

Comment: are you solve it broo. please share the solution